# Does a bid of 'Double' make you the declarer?

Tags: bridge, bidding

South bids, say 2 spades, then west bids 'double', then all others pass.
Does this mean that south is the declarer with the contract being 2 spades doubled?
Or does west win the contract with 2 spades doubled?

My intuition in reading so far suggests that south would still win the auction, but I have not explicitly read that this is the case.

Also, this is not intended to touch on any bidding conventions either, just simply how this affects who wins the auction. I do believe I understand the consequences in the game play or rather the scoring of a doubled bid, but I am simply uncertain who would have won the auction under these circumstances.

Comment: To assist in future interpretation, note the distinction between *bids*, which include only the *calls* naming a denomination and number of odd-tricks from 1 to 7, and *calls* which also include *Pass*, *Double*, and *Redouble*. Only *Bids* have the potential to make one player Declarer, and only if that Player is the first by her side to mention the *denomination* of the *bid*.

Comment: Here are the *Laws of Rubber Bridge - 2014 Edition*: http://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf

Comment: Not a bad question for a beginner. I hope that the answers and comments helped you to learn more about the game.

Comment: Yes they certainly did, I like to be explicitly clear on one level of understanding before moving to the next... In that vein, I feel more comfortable learning about the actual budding language as it pertains to the strategy as mentioned her in the posts and comments. Also, I imagine had I actually played a game with someone who knew how to play this would be a question I would not have needed to ask here. It's not such a popular game with my generation however

Comment: @user74091: I can strongly recommend Richard Pavlick's site: http://www.rpbridge.net/

Comment: Side note: I consider myself a beginner, but as far as I understand, doubling 2S is usually a bad idea. 2SX scores a lot more than 2S when made (because of the game bonus).

Comment: @TwiNight: There are times when 2S* is an excellent contract for the Defenders - when they can collect a "*phone number penalty*" of at least 800.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: South would be the declarer, playing a contract of two spades doubled. Doubles (and redoubles) never change who is declarer, just the scores for making or failing to make the contract.

Comment: Thank you, Im learning to teach a group of friends how to play and none of us have ever played before, and want to make sure i understand all the basic game play thx